# Switch case for the index of an array

Tags: javascript

```
var testVar = [null, true, true, false, false];

//Paulpro's solution (not mine)
switch (testVar.indexOf( true )) {
  case 1:
    console.log('Im in the first group!');
    break;
  case 2:
    console.log('Im in the second group!');
    break;
  case 3:
    console.log('Im in the third group!');
    break;
}
```

testVar is an array like this [null, true, true, false, false, false] for an employee in the first group (index 1 is true) AND second group, but not the third group.

Comment: switch(employee.groups[1]) case true:

Comment: Thank you! I also need employee.groups[2] employee.groups[3] etc

Comment: show your data example

Comment: @TylerL do what @yBrodsky suggested, just change the index from `1` to `index` to run for all of the elements

Comment: `[null, true, true, false, false, false]` this ain't a good data structure. It's cumbersome, unflexible and error-prone. Better would be to have here an Array of `group`-objects for this employee, maybe with a `name` property, and then do something like `employee.groups.forEach(group => console.log("I'm in the group:", group.name));` switches and arrays don't mix very well, because as soon as you The Array changes (size, order) you have to modify every switch that deals with that Array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the position of `true` in the groups array (using [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf?v=example)) and use that for your switch statement:

```
contacts.forEach(function(employee, index){
  switch (employee.groups.indexOf( true )) {
    case 1:
      console.log('Im in the first group!');
      break;
    case 2:
      console.log('Im in the second group!');
      break;
  }
});
```

If the user can be in multiple groups it's better to use a series of if statements:

```
contacts.forEach(function(employee, index){
  if ( employee.groups[1] ) {
      console.log('Im in the first group!');
  }

  if ( employee.groups[2] ) {
      console.log('Im in the second group!');
  }
});
```

Comment: This works if you remove 'break;' for more than one group, e.g. var testVar = [null, true, true, false, false];

Comment: @TylerL This will only work for the first group they are in. I thought that the user could only be in one group when I read your question. If you remove the `break` it won't work correctly. You'll see that if you had a `case 3:`. It will just say that the user is in every group after and including the first one they are actually in.

Comment: @TylerL I updated my answer. I recommend you don't use a switch statement if multiple cases can occur independently from each other (like your case)

Comment: Brilliant solution on the switch case, though. Thank you @Paulpro :)